# atmost K mismatch substrings?

Tags: c, string, algorithm, substring, string-matching

I'm tryring to solve this problem though using brute force I was able to solve it, but 
the following optimised algo is giving me incorrect results for some of the testcases .I tried but couldn;t find the problem with the code can any body help me.

**Problem :**
Given a string S and and integer K, find the integer C which equals the number of pairs of substrings(S1,S2) such that S1 and S2 have equal length and Mismatch(S1, S2) <= K where the mismatch function is defined below.

**The Mismatch Function**

Mismatch(s1,s2) is the number of positions at which the characters in S1 and S2 differ. For example mismatch(bag,boy) = 2 (there is a mismatch in the second and third position), mismatch(cat,cow) = 2 (again, there is a mismatch in the second and third position), Mismatch(London,Mumbai) = 6 (since the character at every position is different in the two strings). The first character in London is ‘L’ whereas it is ‘M’ in Mumbai, the second character in London is ‘o’ whereas it is ‘u’ in Mumbai - and so on.

```
int main() {

int k;
char str[6000];
cin>>k;
cin>>str;
int len=strlen(str);
int i,j,x,l,m,mismatch,count,r;

count=0;

 for(i=0;i<len-1;i++)
   for(j=i+1;j<len;j++)
   {  mismatch=0;
     for(r=0;r<len-j+i;r++)
   {  

       if(str[i+r]!=str[j+r])
         { ++mismatch;
           if(mismatch>=k)break;
         }
    if(mismatch<=k)++count;
   } 
  }
cout<<count;
return 0;
}
```

**Sample test cases**

1. Test case (passing for above code)

   ```
   **input** 
   0
   abab

   **output** 
   3
   ```
2. Test case (**failing** for above code)

   ```
   **input** 
   3
   hjdiaceidjafcchdhjacdjjhadjigfhgchadjjjbhcdgffibeh

   **expected output**
   4034

   **my output**
   4335
   ```

Comment: Please learn to format your code, this looks very bad!  Clear code is half the way to less bugs.

Comment: What's optimized about this code? It looks like brute force to me. Can you post your previous version?

Comment: Also please suggest if there is any faster approach to do this??

Comment: in the previous code I iterating through the compelete substrings again , instead of just comparing the next character. But u are correct it's a very small improvement

Comment: @Groo: Yes, it's optimized by not looping on substring length at any point.  Direct implementation would test all O(n^2) substrings against all O(n) later substrings of the same length, using an O(n) mimsatch count.  That is O(n^4).  This is O(n^3).

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors. First,

```
for(r=1;r<len;r++)
```

should be

```
for(r=1;r<=len-j;r++)
```

since otherwise,

```
str[j+r]
```

would at some point begin comparing characters past the null-terminator (*i.e.* beyond the end of the string). The greatest `r` can be is the remaining number of characters from the `j`th index to the last character.

Second, writing

```
str[i+r]
```

and

```
str[j+r]
```

skips the comparison of the `i`th and `j`th characters since `r` is always at least `1`. You should write

```
for(r=0;r<len-j;r++)
```

Comment: yeah sorry it's actually it's for(r=0;r<=len-j+i;r++) , corrected in the above code , but still not working . Thanks for quick response

Comment: You must mean `r<len-j+1` not `r<len-j+i`. But I disagree. Take `abab`. `len` is 4, right? Say `i` is 0 and `j` is 1. Then `r` is going to count up to and including `4-1+1` according to your code. That's 4. So when you do `str[j+r]`, you get `str[5]`, which is out of bounds. Maybe you meant `r<=len-j-1`, which would have been the same as what I wrote, `r<len-j`. Oh, or, maybe you meant `r<=len-(j-1)`, which would have been correct as well.

Comment: no I meant r<len-j+i, according to ur example i=0,j=1  , then r is going to count from r=0 to r<(4-1+0)=3 .So r will take values r=0,r=1,r=2 correct right.Because str[j+r] , would be max str[1+2]=str[3]??

Comment: @decoder: if `len=4`, `i=2` and `j=3`, then `len-j+i` is `3`. This means that you will check if `str[2+2]==str[3+2]` at some point, which is outside of the string.

Comment: @Groo got it , thanks man now getting correct answer . but still getting TLE for some inputs , any faster approach for this problem

Answer (score 1):

You have two basic errors.  You are quitting when mismatches>=k instead of mismatches>k (mismatches==k is an acceptable number) and you are letting r get too large.  These skew the final count in opposite directions but, as you see, the second error "wins".

The real inner loop should be:

```
for (r=0; r<len-j; ++r)
{
     if (str[i+r] != str[j+r])
     {
           ++mismatch;
           if (mismatch > k)
                break;
      }
      ++count;
 }
```

r is an index into the substring, and j+r MUST be less than len to be valid for the right substring.  Since i<j, if str[j+r] is valid, then so it str[i+r], so there's no need to have i involved in the upper limit calculation.

Also, you want to break on mismatch>k, not on >=k, since k mismatches are allowed.

Next, if you test for too many mismatches after incrementing mismatch, you don't have to test it again before counting.

Finally, the upper limit of r<len-j (instead of <=) means that the trailing '\0' character won't be compared as part of the str[j+r] substring.  You were comparing that and more when j+r >= len, but mismatches was less than k when that first happened.

---

Note: You asked about a faster method.  There is one, but the coding is more involved.  Make the outer loop on the difference delta between starting index values. (0<delta<len) Then, count all acceptable matches with something like:

```
count = 0;
for delta = 1 to len-1
    set i=0; j=delta; mismatches=0; r=0; 
    while j < len
        .. find k'th mismatch, or end of str:
        while mismatches < k and j+r<len
            if str[i+r] != str[j+r] then mismatches=mismatches+1
            r = r+1
        end while
        .. extend r to cover any trailing matches:
        while j+r<len and str[i+r]==str[j+r]
            r + r+1
        end while

        .. arrive here with r being the longest string pair starting at str[i]
        .. and str[j] with no more than k mismatches. This loop will add (r) 
        .. to the count and advance i,j one space to the right without recounting
        .. the character mismatches inside.  Rather, if a mismatch is dropped off
        .. the front, then mismatches is decremented by 1.
        repeat
            count = count + r
            if str[i] != str[j] then mismatches=mismatches-1
            i = i+1, j = j+1, r = r-1
        until mismatches < k
    end if
end while
```

That's pseudocode, and also pseudocorrect.  The general idea is to compare all substrings with starting indices differing by (delta) in one pass, starting and the left, and increasing the substring length r until the end of the source string is reached or k+1 mismatches have been seen.  That is, str[j+r] is either the end of the string, or the camel's-back-breaking mismatch position in the right substring.  That makes r substrings that had k or fewer mismatches starting at str[i] and str[j].

So count those r substrings and move to the next positions i=i+1,j=j+1 and new length r=r-1, reducing the mismatch count if unequal characters were dropped off the left side.

It should be pretty easy to see that on each loop either r increases by 1 or j increases by 1 and (j+r) stays the same.  Both will j and (j+r) will reach len in O(n) time, so the whole thing is O(n^2).

Edit: I fixed the handing of r, so the above should be even more pseudocorrect. The improvement to O(n^2) runtime might help.

Re-edit: Fixed comment bugs.
Re-re-edit: More typos in algorithm, mostly mismatches misspelled and incremented by 2 instead of 1.

Comment: What's the value of `delta`? Does it ever change?

Comment: I mentioned that in passing.  There's an implied outer loop over 0 &lt; delta &lt; len.  All of the "interesting" stuff happens in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike I have some modifications in your logic and here is the correct code for it...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
long long int k,c=0;
string s;
cin>>k>>s;
int len = s.length();
for(int gap = 1 ; gap < len; gap ++)
{
    int i=0,j=gap,mm=0,tmp_len=0; 


        while (mm <=k && (j+tmp_len)<len)
        {
            if (s[i+tmp_len] != s[j+tmp_len])
                mm++;
            tmp_len++;
        }
       // while (((j+tmp_len)<len) && (s[i+tmp_len]==s[j+tmp_len]))
         //   tmp_len++;
        if(mm>k){tmp_len--;mm--;} 
        do{
            c = c + tmp_len ;
            if (s[i] != s[j]) mm--;

                i++;
                j++;

            tmp_len--;
            while (mm <=k && (j+tmp_len)<len)
            {
            if (s[i+tmp_len] != s[j+tmp_len])
                mm++;
            tmp_len++;
            }
            if(mm>k){tmp_len--;mm--;} 
        }while(tmp_len>0);

}
cout<<c<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The original had only the misspelling of "mismatches" and the typo of "mismatches = mismatches + 2" instead of + 1.  That's fixed and a quick implementation matches both of the test cases.